# Django template vars and list indices

Tags: django, templates, variables

I have a strange problem.

I use paginator to display some data in each page, however, I do not see any possibility to add other attributes I need to the model, so I have created another list of dicts with additional data.

In template:

> {% for x in p.object_list %}
>
> ```
> {% with c=forloop.counter0 %}
>
>     {{ info.c }} <!-- prints nothing, while {{ info }} prints all the list of dicts and {{ c }} prints 0, for example. {{ info.0 }} prints everything as intended too. -->
>
> {% endwith %}
> ```
>
> {% endfor %}

Answer (score 1):

`{{ info.c }}` accesses `info['c']`, `info.c`, etc. You want the [`slice`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) filter instead.